# Set AM/PM in English language in xamarin Forms Timepicker on iOS devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a timepicker control in my application and want to display the time in 12 hours format. But in iOS the AM and PM is displaying in different languages based on the region. I want to display it in English for all regions. How to implement that, please help me. I tried with custom timepicker also but didn't work.

```
 <TimePicker BackgroundColor="Red"
             Format="hh:mm tt"
             Time="{Binding StartTime}"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Localization in iOS is what you need, you can specify default and supported languages in `Info.plist`, and add supported `.strings` files in `floder.lproj` to your project. It will be available if you have resource files and add key-value pairs in localized languages. If the user sets the "preferred language" in Settings, iOS will automatically find the user's favorite language first. you can refer to: [How iOS Determines the Language For Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html)

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>  
<array>  
    <string>en</string>  
    <string>es</string>  
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string
```

You also could set AppleLanguages to change the language:

```
 NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings("XX"), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));  
 NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
```

For more information, you could refer to:

[Localization in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/#specifying-default-and-supported-languages-in-infoplist)

[Xamarin.Forms String and Image Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows)